# Node js router 404 with params

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wanna pass parameter to page. But have 404. My code:
app.js

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();
```

routes/index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/profile/:id', function (req, res) {
   var id = req.params.id;
   console.log(id);
   res.render('profile', {id: id});
});
```

and i try http://localhost:3000/profile?id=56e2c3c2cdde3f64302ac154 but have Error: Not Found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your route should be looks like:

```
 http://localhost:3000/profile/56e2c3c2cdde3f64302ac154
```

It is automaticaly set `req.params.id`.

Comment: Спасибо! А можно как-то сделать чтобы через знак вопроса было? Thanks! How i can use 'profile?id=...'?

Comment: then you have to use another property `req.query.id` and change your route path to `/profile` instead of `/profile/:id`

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between Path param and Query param . The Url you have defined

```
/profile/:id
```

Says to the routing framework that , I expect id as Path param i.e part of the resource path . But in the url request you made

```
 http://localhost:3000/profile?id=56e2c3c2cdde3f64302ac154
```

You are sending id as query param . So the routing framework is unaware of the url with id as a query param . Hence it returns a 404 meaning "the server could not find what was requested" .